# How to get rid of the 2d object turning over when rotating?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made the rotation of the object in the direction of its movement (the object always moves and does not stop), but there was a problem: the sprite turns over when the object moves in the opposite direction. How can I get rid of this? I tried to fix the rotation on all axes except z, but nothing good came of it (just stopped turning).

Code with rotation:

```
void Update()
{
    Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, rb.velocity);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed);
}
```